# XSD cutom type for fraction numbers with / symbol

Tags: xml, types, xsd, schema, fractions

Hi fellow programmers,

I am trying to create custom XSD type extension to accept double or two doubles with "/" symbol in the middle. This way I want to express fraction numbers. For example:

```
<some_element>12.34</some_element>
<some_element>1/23</some_element>
<some_element>12.34/56.78</some_element>
<some_element>12.34/56.78</some_element>
<some_element>-1/2</some_element>
```

must be valid.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define it as a restriction of xs:string using a pattern facet. The pattern for xs:double is given in the XSD 1.1 spec as

```
(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)([Ee](\+|-)?[0-9]+)? |(\+|-)?INF|NaN
```

and from that it's trivial to allow one of these, or two separated by  "/"

Comment: Thank you. With a bit of wikipedia about REGEX I made it work. Pattern I created: "(\+|-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(/(\+|-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)"


Edit: it will not accept scientific double notation.